# If Post Published Date or Modified Date is 1 Year or Older, Display Notice on Post Page

Tags: php, posts, date, date-time

I need a way to inform visitors if the post published date **or** modified date is older than 1 year and if so, display a message on the post page.

I have added an code to my `content-single.php` file, but without the desired results in terms of checking against both published and updated time.

**Example:**

```
if (strtotime($post->post_date) < strtotime('-1 year')){
    echo 'Old Post';
} else {
    echo 'Not Old Post';
}
```

Any ideas as I'm in the dark here..

Comment: I guess you can look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56799991/check-a-post-published-date-if-its-more-than-two-years-old - and modify it to suit your needs :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you're just checking for the post date.
You'll need to check for 'post_modified' aswell. You can find the complete post-object here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/#user-contributed-notes

You can modify the check to look something like this:

```
if (strtotime($post->post_date) < strtotime('-1 year') && strtorime($post->post_modified) < strtotime('-1 year')){
    echo 'Old Post';
} else {
    echo 'Not Old Post';
}
```

That should check for both.